# Why is "design matrix of correlation parameters" a proxy for the "actual covariance matrix/working correlation matrix?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, covariance-matrix, generalized-estimating-equations, geepack

The example shows that knowing the design matrix of correlation parameters is sufficient to specify the working correlation.

```
genZcor {geepack}   R Documentation
genZcor
Description
constructs the design matrix for the correlation structures: independence, echangeable, ar1 and unstructured The user will need this function only as a basis to construct a user defined correlation structure: use genZcor to get the design matrix Z for the unstructured correlation and define the specific correlation structure by linear combinations of the columns of Z.

Usage
genZcor(clusz, waves, corstrv)
Arguments
clusz   
integer vector giving the number of observations in each cluster

waves   
integer vector, obervations in the same cluster with values of wave i and j have the correlation sigma_ij

corstrv 
correlation structures: 1=independence,2=exchangeable,3=ar1, 4=unstructured

Value
the design matrix for the correlation structure

Author(s)
Jun Yan jyan.stat@gmail.com

See Also
fixed2Zcor

Examples

#example to construct a Toeplitz correlation structure
#    sigma_ij=sigma_|i-j|

#data set with 5 clusters and maximally 4 observations (visits) per cluster
 gendat <- function() {
       id <- gl(5, 4, 20)
       visit <- rep(1:4, 5)
       y <- rnorm(id)
       dat <- data.frame(y, id, visit)[c(-2,-9),]
}

set.seed(88)
dat<-gendat()

#generating the design matrix for the unstructured correlation
zcor <- genZcor(clusz = table(dat$id), waves = dat$visit, corstrv=4)
# defining the Toeplitz structure 
zcor.toep<-matrix(NA, nrow(zcor),3)
zcor.toep[,1]<-apply(zcor[,c(1,4,6)],1,sum)
zcor.toep[,2]<-apply(zcor[,c(2,5)],1,sum)
zcor.toep[,3]<-zcor[,3]

zfit1 <- geese(y ~ 1,id = id, data = dat,
                   corstr = "userdefined", zcor = zcor.toep)


zfit2 <- geeglm(y ~ 1,id = id, data = dat,
                   corstr = "userdefined", zcor = zcor.toep)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sure, in the supplied example of the package, they specifically set up the correlation matrix. In general, the structure is unknown, and the correlation structure is just treated as an approximation for the score equations. If you know the correlation structure already, you might as well specify it to improve efficiency ...